# How to echo a MySQLi row in escaped PHP code, inside an HTML block

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I'm wondering what is the appropriate syntax is to echo a row from MySQLi code in a block of HTML text. I'm working on a page that uses PHP code at the start to determine if a session is started and to post comments that user has posted, after pulling said comments from a MySQLi database. The interesting and confusing part is, I've accomplished what I'm trying to do in one HTML div, but I can't seem to get it to work in the next.

```
    <?php
    $page_title = "store";
    require_once('connectvars.php');
    require_once('startsession.php');
    require_once('header.php');

    // Connect to the DB
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    // Grab location data from the DB
    // Grab post data
    $query2 = "SELECT sp.post_id, sp.admin_id, sp.post, sp.date, sa.admin_id, s.store_name, s.store_city, s.store_state, s.store_zip,s.store_phone, s.store_email, s.store_address FROM store_posts sp, store_admin sa, stores s WHERE sp.admin_id='$admin_id' and sa.admin_id='$admin_id' and s.admin_id='$admin_id'ORDER BY date DESC";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 0) {
        $blankwall = "Empty feed? '<a href=manage.php><u>Click here</u></a> to manage posts and communicate with your customers!";
    }
?>
<body>
<div id="content">
<!-- BANNER & CONTENT-->
    <h2>Recent Posts</h2>
  <div id="store_wrap">
        <div id="left_col">
        <br />
        <?php
            **// Loop through posts and show them
            if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 0) {
                echo $blankwall;
            }
                else {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
                // Show the posts
                echo '' . $row['post'] . ' | ';
                echo date('M j, Y g:i A', strtotime($row['date']));
                echo '<br /><hr />';
            }**
            }
        ?>
        </div><!-- closes left_col -->
```

So all the above code is there to query the DB to grab the correct array and then show $row['posts'] in the HTML div below the PHP code, titled left_col. I am trying to do the exact same thing in the next div but instead of echoing $row['posts'], I want to echo rows such as $row['store_city'] to have the page display the store's location after pulling it out of the previously selected array. Here's my non-functioning code for that part:

```
<div id="right_col">
            <div id="store_picture">
          <img src="images/store.jpg" style="width:325px;"/>
            </div><!-- closes picture --><br />
            <div id="store_address">
                <br /><br /><h2>Location Info</h2>
                <?php
                if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
                    echo '<p>' . $row['store_city']. '</p>';
                    }
            }
                mysqli_close($dbc);
                ?>

            </div><!-- closes store_address -->
            <div id="store_info">
                <p></p>
            </div><!-- closes store_info -->
        </div><!-- closes right_col -->
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div><!-- closes store_wrap -->
</div><!-- closes content -->
```

For whatever reason, the second time, when I try to echo data from that array, I just have empty space within that div. I don't get any errors. I just don't get...anything. Therefore, I think this is a syntax issue. I've tried exactly the same thing I did with the section where I echo $row['post'] and it isn't working.

Comment: You are hoping to loop a second time on the same result set in `$data`?  If so, you would need to either 1) loop once and store all rows fetched into an array, which you can then loop over as many times as you want, or 2) rewind the record pointer back to the beginning of the result set with `mysqli_data_seek($data, 0)` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php  because once you've fetched all rows, the next call to `mysqli_fetch_array()` will return false.

Comment: I actually do have error reporting on and my original code doesn't have the spelling error, so this is odd. Going to edit the post to fix that now. 

With regards to the question, I see what you're saying. I didn't know mysqli_fetch_array() would return false after being called once. That's likely my problem. I will try using the data seek function once I figure out exactly how it should be implemented, and reply with the results. Thanks!

Comment: The simplest fix is to just call `mysqli_data_seek($data, 0);` immediately before the second time you do `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))`  That isn't the most efficient method because it requires MySQL to supply rows twice, but it is the easiest path to get your code working.

Comment: I will try that now and report the results. Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying for here? I'm new to PHP and MySQLi (obviously) and I was somewhat concerned that making multiple calls to the DB could be problematic. For that reason, I didn't try simply running another query in each PHP block. I assumed that would be horribly inefficient and it just felt...wrong.

Comment: Definitely don't query twice. If you are getting back only a small number of rows (say, < 100) storing all of them at once into a PHP array is probably better than going back to MySQL to re-fetch them. But if you are returning thousands of rows it may be better to re-fetch because you will save memory in the web server. It won't make a giant difference though unless this has to scale really large.  I'll summarize both these things into a proper answer below..

Comment: I implemented your suggested idea and it totally worked! I had no idea `mysqli_fetch_array()` could essentially only be used once and this solves the problem. Ideally, I would only return one row at a time because all of these rows should come from the same entry in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chief issue you're facing is that you make a second attempt at fetching rows from the `$data` MySQLi result resource object after already having fetched them once.  This won't work as intended, as MySQL keeps an internal recordset pointer which advances every time `mysqli_fetch_array()` is called. So when the end of the first loop is reached, the pointer is at the end of the recordset and a subsequent call will return `FALSE`.

Therefore, your second loop gets nowhere because its first call to `mysqli_fetch_array()` returns `FALSE`, exiting the loop. You have two options.

The quickest fix is to just rewind the record pointer [using `mysqli_data_seek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php).  Called right before the *second* loop, it will set the pointer back to the first record, allowing you to fetch them all again.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {
  // Rewind the record pointer back to the first record
  mysqli_data_seek($data, 0);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    // note addition of htmlspecialchars() to escape the string for HTML!
    echo '<p>' .htmlspecialchars($row['store_city']). '</p>';
  }
}
```

Perhaps a better option if your recordset is small is to fetch all rows into an array once, then use that array with a `foreach` loop for both your subsequent output loops:

```
// To hold all rows
$rows = array();
// Do the query
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);
// (don't forget to check for errors)
if ($data) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    // Append the row onto the $rows array
    $rows[] = $row;
  }
}
else{
  // handle the error somehow...
}
```

Later, instead of using `$data` again, you will loop over `$rows` with a `foreach` loop.

```
// use count($rows)
if (count($rows) == 0) {
  echo $blankwall;
}
else {
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // Show the posts
    echo '' . $row['post'] . ' | ';
    echo date('M j, Y g:i A', strtotime($row['date']));
    echo '<br /><hr />';
  }
}
```

...And do the same thing again for your second loop later in the code.  It's recommended to use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) on the string fields output from the query where appropriate.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate the suggestions. I'll try out using a `foreach` loop and also look up the use of `htmlspecialchars()`. Thank you again!

Comment: Using the `foreach` loop works a little too well! Because I'm looping in the later code from the same array as the original, I'm echoing the row multiple times for each row the query finds. I tried creating a token but I don't know how to stop the loop and update the token after it has run once. Should I create a different array for the second foreach loop? Also, I'm new to the site and unsure if this is the way to ask a follow-up question so please excuse me if this is the wrong place.

Comment: @Kasaius I don't fully understand what you're describing.  Normally, if you need clarification on an answer as it is posted, it is appropriate to ask for it in the comments. In your case though, it sounds like your code has changed significantly  in the course of integrating this, and you're now facing an entirely different issue related to the integration. It would probably be better to ask it as a new question with your current code, explaining what the current issue is. After posting, if you @ me here with a link I can take a look at it if the community hasn't already solved it.

Comment: I was struggling to describe the issue while staying under the character limit. I haven't changed anything except implementing the foreach clauses but I think I initially left some information out regarding my page's layout. I'm looping through the array built by the one query above but that query selects more rows than I need for the second foreach echo block. So it builds the correct array for the initial echo block, but the second one needs fewer rows from the DB. I believe I'll have to make two queries after all, so I will try that.

Comment: What is the condition that the first uses which second doesn't? You should be able to make the query either sort or identify the rows so you don't need to query twice.  To break out of the loop you would do `foreach ($rows as $row) {if (some_condition()) break; /* normal loop stuff... */}`

Comment: My goal is to have the left div loop through each row of posts and echo them onto the page, while the right div will echo the page owner's location information (store_city, store_state, etc.). The query grabs every row for that user ID and the first foreach loop goes through and posts each`$row['post']` in the left div. But looping in the right div to echo `$row['store_city']` makes it echo the data in that row once for every time it echoed the data from `$row['post']`. So if I have three posts echoed on the left, I have three cities echoed on the right, and I only want one.

Comment: So the city info is always in the first row returned by the query?  You don't need the second loop if that's the case - you just need `echo $rows[0]['store_city']`

Comment: Perfect. That's what I was looking for. Again, the problem is a function I didn't know existed. I have never seen the array() with a number in the brackets, so I didn't know that was an option. Never crossed my mind to put the [0] after `$rows`. Hopefully I'll continue to pick up more tricks as I go. Thanks again!